# Why add an existing local IIS website to Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, projects-and-solutions

I've always previously worked with visual studio solutions with "projects" in them.

Recently, I was given an assignment to work with a VS solution with projects AND a local IIS website in in. The person who worked on the solution is not in the company anymore, and none of us cannot really figure out why it was set up that way. All other projects seems to be dependent on that website, and changing its web.config seem to affect them.  The entire setup has mixed projects (MVC, Webforms, etc.)

Can anyone shed a light what is the need for adding a local IIS website in a solution along with other projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find the source code first. Without that, any discussion is pointless. It is normal for multiple web apps to live in a single web site, so I don't think that's surprising.

Comment: Lex Li. Is there anything particular in the source code that would be significant to write here? I am just not use to having a web site in the solution, along with projects.  So if you can point me to the right direction (some links with similar set up, maybe? tried to search but cannot find any), then that will really help.

Comment: If you inherit an ASP.NET Web Site (is that what you observed from the code?), which was an ancient feature, then except rewrite it you won't get any easier option. But if you inherit it from someone else, it is less likely that you would be allowed to totally rewrite it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like a convoluted setup of mix and match projects that is expensive to rewrite.  The "ancient feature" mention helps a bit (probably why I cannot find that much info in the web anymore).  But I just wanted to know somebody can shed some light behind the reasoning why anybody would feel the need to set it up this way (mix projects with website in one solution), to make some sense out of it.

Comment: "Feel the need“? Nope. A long time ago you can only create Web site projects, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227432.aspx While it does feature some unique features, later Web application projects supersede them, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, Lex Li. Okay, perhaps the reason was -- that was their only option at that time.  These are old applications.